# Read the contents of a script from a plugin in roblox

Tags: roblox

How would I be able to read the contents of a script without the player doing it manually

ex: a plugin that can read scripts and make changes to them when activated

Comment: See [Script.Source](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Script/Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this... Barely. [Script.Source](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Script/Source) (as noted above) is the only way to do this, however keep in mind that it is `RobloxPluginSecurity` (can only be used from a plugin), which renders most used of the property useless.

Besides, outside of plugins there is not much use that would be practical.